# how to convert BitmapDrawable or Bitmap to ImageBitmap in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I need to change `Bitmap?` or `BitmapDrawable` to `ImageBitmap` and show it with `coil`
here is my code

```
val bitmap = BlurhashDecoder.decode(blurhash, 4, 3)
Image(
    bitmap = bitmap as ImageBitmap,
    modifier = modifier,
    contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
    contentDescription = ""
)
```

when I run it I get this error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.Bitmap cannot be cast to androidx.compose.ui.graphics.ImageBitmap
```

Comment: I can cast my `bitmap` to BitmapDrawable with `bitmap.toDrawable(resources)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use `bitmap.asImageBitmap()` to convert a `bitmap` to `ImageBitmap`